# Why isn't some of my jQuery loading until I refresh the page?

Tags: jquery, onload

Having a problem where some of the scripts on my page don't seem to load until refresh.
The page is [here](http://www.artforeating.co.uk/portia/rainbowwhitebg800.html).
The first iframe (click far left-hand side of image) doesn't load the Galleria plug-in until the iframe is manually refreshed. Also, the qTip script on the main page often behaves similarly, despite $(document).ready(function(){ being included.

So, my question is, how can I stop this behaviour, or have the iframe automatically reload onload once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me as well in Chrome, though the headings (e.g., "Installations") only appear in Firefox FYI.

Comment: Even the thumbnails in the third (canvas) section? How strange that it's misbehaving for me...

Comment: It seems like i'm going crazy - fresh install of Safari and everything loads EXCEPT the qTips giving the mouseover page titles!

Comment: Also, running Error Console I seem to get "Fatal error: Width & height not found" for Galleria, which may explain why that doesn't load until refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on Safari 5 (no reloads required). Could be a caching problem. Try using [cache-busting](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/js_page.html), maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't seem to fix this, and it's definitely not working on multiple machines...

I think it may be to do with the iframes being in hidden divs when the main page first loads. I read something about using the "off-left" technique instead, but not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably pass height as an option, Gallerie tried to extract the height from your css, but the best way to make sure a height is detected is by passing height as an options.

example:

```
.galleria({
    height: 400
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. I had already tried adding that, see below:           
        $('#gallery').galleria({
            height: 450,
 width: 1024